# Flask WTform validate_on_submit() returning False

Tags: html, validation, flask, wtforms

looking to test my first CSRF validation with a POST request, and everything it seems is in place the CSRF is included in the HTML markup as a hidden tag when i render it in the browser.

My Flask app route looks like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'itsasecret'
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_and_post():
    """Get route to show the homepage"""
    form = AddSnackForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'form accepted successfully.'

    else:
        return render_template("add_snack.html", form=form)
```

And the template I have to render via "add_snack.html" is as follows

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
{{form.hidden_tag()}}


{% for field in form %}

{% if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}


<p>{{field.label}}</p>
<p>{{field}}</p>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Submit

However, each time the validate_on_submit, returns false.

Any ideas on what might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to loop through the form and render each field, instead render the fields in the form individually

replace the jinja code from where the for loop start and
you can try it like this for every field

```
<div>
  {{ form.field.label }}
  {{ form.field }}
</div>
```

replace field with the objects in your form class e.g., name etc.

do this for every field so that the code will look sth like this

```
<div>
  {{ form.field1.label }}
  {{ form.field1 }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form.field2.label }}
  {{ form.field2 }}
</div>
<div>
  {{ form.fieldn.label }}
  {{ form.fieldn }}
</div>
```

also try using

{{ form.csrf_token }}

instead of

{{form.hidden_tag()}}

I hope this helps.